# SSRS HTML Tag in Text Box not interpreting a full HREF tag

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

I am using Report Builder 2016 and I am trying to include an  tag in my text box.  However, SSRS is not interpreting the full URL string with parameters.  For example my tag is the following

```
<a href=http://www.google.com?ID=123456>some text</a>
```

SSRS will only interpret up to the equal sign of the parameters:  `http://www.google.com?ID`.  By switching the placeholder properties of the text box expression back to Test from HTML I can confirm that the full URL string is being passed in.

Here is the full Expression being used. This is in a Matrix Table that display a Calendar format. The `ID_URL` field is the full URL string:

```
=IIF(Fields!Site.Value <> ""
    ,JOIN(LOOKUPSET(Fields!DayNumberOfMonth.Value
                   ,Fields!DayNumberOfMonth.Value
                   ,Fields!ID_URL.Value
                   ,"Month"
                   )
         ,"<br>"
         )
    ,""
    )
```

Any ideas on how to get SSRS to interpret the entire `href` string with it's following parameters?

Comment: Is that the entire contents of your textbox, or is that only a fragment?  If only a part, could you add the rest of the contents to your question please?

Comment: Here is the full Expression being used.  This is in a Matrix Table that display a Calendar format.  The ID_URL field is the full URL string:

=IIF(Fields!Site.Value <> "", JOIN(
                LOOKUPSET(Fields!DayNumberOfMonth.Value,
                                Fields!DayNumberOfMonth.Value,
                                Fields!ID_URL.Value,
                                "Month"
                                ),
"<br>"),"")

Comment: I have also tried the HTML in a standard table and it behaves the same and will not interpret any parameters from the equal sign on.

Comment: Is this just the one URL?  Or will each text box potentially have several?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have the URL in your source data, I think you will find this a lot easier to simply display what you want the user to see in the textbox and set the `Action` property of the textbox to go to the URL returned in the `ID_URL` field.

If you need to display more than one URL, you could also encode the URL to not contain any special characters.  For `=` this would be `%3D`.  I have not tested this, though I believe you can also call the `URLEncode` function:

```
System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(YourUrl)
```

You will need to add an assembly reference to do this though, which you can follow through [this tutorial](http://capstonebi.blogspot.com/2010/04/url-encoding-in-reporting-services.html) if you are unsure on how.

---

If you absolutely cannot use assembly references, you can manually add a load of `replace` functions for any special characters you have, using [this W3Schools web page](https://www.w3schools.com/Tags/ref_urlencode.asp) as a reference.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I used the %3D for the equal sign but I also had to use a Tiny URL in order to get it to work.  This appears to be a bug in SSRS 2016 in which i hope they fix someday.